# Does this piston look normal?

Tags: piston

I noticed a slightly reddish color on my pistons.  Is it normal?
It's an '08 Mercedes-Benz E350, gasoline (petrol), with 35k miles.

[image: Piston]

Here is a little color correction:
[image: Enhanced contrast]

Comment: petrol, diesel or lpg (gas)

Comment: It is a petrol.